# Como acrescentar um icone em uma imagem ativa

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer que a imagem que estiver ativa fique com um incone do coração em cima, do Font Awesome, **ou** um coração em png, tentei a pseudo-classe **:Active** porém não funcionou.

**https://fontawesome.com/icons/heart** 
Se alguem poder da uma força, porque tentei colocar um coração em PNG em cima da imagem ativa, porém mesmo assim não consegui.

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-control {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 102px;
  height: 92px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 32px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="slider__nav-bar">   
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0JGIa6o.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kR6A8GJ.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/asycxT9.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
        </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Cara coloca a `imagem` dentro de uma `label` junto com um `input` do tipo `radio`. Se o `label` for clicado o ícone aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um exemplo simples pra vc ajustar o CSS ao seu gosto...

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-control {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 102px;
  height: 92px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 32px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.slider__nav-bar {
  display: flex;
}
label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
[name="hart"],
i.fa-heart {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
[name="hart"]:checked + i.fa-heart {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="slider__nav-bar">   
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="hart">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0JGIa6o.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="hart">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kR6A8GJ.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="hart">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/asycxT9.png" alt="" class="nav-control">
  </label>
</div>
```